# Meaning of uniform distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

I'm studying stochastic calculus now.
And I found in my textbook that strictly review elementary probability theory.

But I suddenly confused the notion of uniform distribution.

I thought when we see uniform distribution on the 2 dimensional space, it just flat line on X-Y graph.

like below picture(from wikipedia), uniform distribution has the function $P[a,b] = \frac{1}{b-a}$

[image]

However In my textbook, it just change it's function from $P$ to $P_{tilda}$, I mean from $b-a$ to $b^2 - a^2$.
[image]

I think $P[a,b] = \frac{1}{b-a} ≠ b-a ≠ b^2 - a^2$. So both equation about $P[a,b]$ in the textbook are not uniform distribution. But the textbook said, $b-a$ is uniform, $b^2 - a^2$ is **no longer has the uniform distribution**.

So I'm now confused of what is the real meaning of 'uniform' in probability..!

In short, What is the meaning and reason of the sentence in the above picture : **"Under P tilda, the random variable X no longer has the uniform distribution"**?

*the text book is stochastic calculus for finance Ⅱ by shreve

Comment: TL;DR. Apparently you are confusing the *density* $f$ of the uniform distribution on $[a,b]$ with its integral. The density must be $f(x)=1/(b-a)$ for the integral over $[a,b]$ to be one (probability distribution). The example 1.2.4 from that book considers a uniform distribution on $\color{red}{[0,1]}$. Now it seems you are confusing $0$ with $a$ and $1$ with $b$. Note every $a$ in different references means the same thing!

Comment: You mean that 1. probability is integral of density function $f$ 2. So in the textbook, if $P[a,b] = b-a$ then it means it's density function is constant "1". Therefore it is uniform distribution. 3. However, if $P[a,b] = b^2-a^2$ then it means it's density function is $x$; considering that $(∫^b_af(x)dx = Probability)$. Therefore it is not uniform distribution because density function is monotonic increasing. Am I right?

Comment: .You are right.

Answer (score 1):

I should not have confused about the definition.

**Definition** : $P(X∈[a,b]) = ∫^b_af(t)dt$

As Kurt.G mentioned, Probability is integral of density function : $f(x)$

Flat line of uniform distribution on the graph means that we deal with "density funciton".

For example, Let's say we are focusing the interval $0 ≤ a ≤ b ≤ 1$.
To be one(probability's property) when integrated, it needs to be $f(x) = \frac{1}{b-a}$

It means $∫^b_af(t)dt = ∫^b_a\frac{1}{b-a}dt = \frac{1}{b-a}[t]^b_a = \frac{b-a}{b-a} = 1$

So the textbook tells us about "Probability" not "density" function.

Again, $P[a,b] = ∫^b_af(t)dt$.

To be $P[a,b] = b-a$, $f(t)$ needs to be constants. Just "1".
Then it can translated that now we have flat density function, meaning uniform distribution.

Also To be $P[a,b] = b^2 - a^2 $, $f(t)$ needs to have first order term with "$t$"
It means density function is increasing, therefore it is not uniform distribution.